# Bundle update requres to restart karaf

Tags: java, hibernate, osgi, apache-karaf

When specific bundle, which uses Hibernate is updated, persisting exception occurs:

```
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy71.persist(Unknown Source)
        at com.aurimas.edi.persistence.service.impl.Hl7StagingAreaServiceImpl.persistHl7Message(Hl7StagingAreaServiceImpl.java:37)[249:com.aurimas.edi.osgi-adapter-bi-sa-db:1.0.0.SNAPSHOT]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.8.0_60]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)[:1.8.0_60]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.8.0_60]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)[:1.8.0_60]
        at org.apache.aries.proxy.impl.ProxyHandler$1.invoke(ProxyHandler.java:54)
        at org.apache.aries.proxy.impl.ProxyHandler.invoke(ProxyHandler.java:119)
        at com.aurimas.edi.persistence.service.impl.$Hl7StagingAreaServiceImpl1100807931.persistHl7Message(Unknown Source)[249:com.aurimas.edi.osgi-adapter-bi-sa-db:1.0.0.SNAPSHOT]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.8.0_60]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)[:1.8.0_60]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.8.0_60]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)[:1.8.0_60]
        at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo.invoke(MethodInfo.java:408)[76:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.doProceed(MethodInfo.java:279)[76:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.proceed(MethodInfo.java:252)[76:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:167)[76:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72)[76:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:398)[76:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)[76:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118)[76:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)[76:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)[76:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.camel.component.directvm.DirectVmProcessor.process(DirectVmProcessor.java:55)[76:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.camel.component.directvm.DirectVmProducer.process(DirectVmProducer.java:55)[76:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:120)[76:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72)[76:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:398)[76:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)[76:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118)[76:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)[76:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)[76:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.camel.component.directvm.DirectVmProcessor.process(DirectVmProcessor.java:55)[76:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.camel.component.directvm.DirectVmProducer.process(DirectVmProducer.java:55)[76:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:120)[76:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72)[76:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:398)[76:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)[76:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118)[76:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)[76:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)[76:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processExchange(GenericFileConsumer.java:423)[76:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processBatch(GenericFileConsumer.java:211)[76:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:175)[76:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:187)[76:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.14.0]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:114)[76:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.14.0]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)[:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)[:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)[:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)[:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)[:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)[:1.8.0_60]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.8.0_60]
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor67.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.8.0_60]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)[:1.8.0_60]
        at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.context.transaction.impl.JTAEntityManagerHandler.invoke(JTAEntityManagerHandler.java:185)
        ... 53 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy75.persist(Unknown Source)
        ... 57 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor67.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.8.0_60]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)[:1.8.0_60]
        at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.impl.EntityManagerProxyFactory$EMHandler.invoke(EntityManagerProxyFactory.java:31)
        ... 58 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of com.aurimas.edi.entity.message.HL7Message.id
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)[142:org.hibernate.entitymanager:4.3.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)[142:org.hibernate.entitymanager:4.3.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683)[142:org.hibernate.entitymanager:4.3.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1187)[142:org.hibernate.entitymanager:4.3.6.Final]
        ... 62 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of com.aurimas.edi.entity.message.HL7Message.id
        at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor$DirectGetter.get(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:60)[141:org.hibernate.core:4.3.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:346)[141:org.hibernate.core:4.3.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4746)[141:org.hibernate.core:4.3.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.isTransient(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4465)[141:org.hibernate.core:4.3.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:243)[141:org.hibernate.core:4.3.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.getEntityState(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:511)[141:org.hibernate.core:4.3.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:116)[141:org.hibernate.core:4.3.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75)[141:org.hibernate.core:4.3.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811)[141:org.hibernate.core:4.3.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784)[141:org.hibernate.core:4.3.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789)[141:org.hibernate.core:4.3.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1181)[142:org.hibernate.entitymanager:4.3.6.Final]
        ... 62 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Long field com.aurimas.edi.entity.message.HL7Message.id to com.aurimas.edi.entity.message.HL7Message
        at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)[:1.8.0_60]
        at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)[:1.8.0_60]
        at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58)[:1.8.0_60]
        at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:36)[:1.8.0_60]
        at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:393)[:1.8.0_60]
        at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor$DirectGetter.get(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:57)[141:org.hibernate.core:4.3.6.Final]
        ... 73 more
```

After restarting Karaf this problem disappears and persisting works.

**I don't want to restart karaf each time.**

I found out that after my bundle update I need to do these steps:

1. Refresh hibernate-osgi bundle
2. Restart my bundle

And then everything starts working, but I don't want to refresh hibernate-osgi and restart my bundle each time as well.

I'm using Apache Karaf 3.0.3, Hibernate 4.3.6, Java 1.8.0_60.

Answer (score 1):

Note that this is absolutely expected in Hibernate ORM OSGi 4.x and 5.0.x.  Restarting your application bundle has disastrous consequences for hibernate-osgi and ultimately hibernate-core.  Until https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9818 is corrected (we will work on it soon), Hibernate ORM OSGi should be considered **static**, rather than dynamically reacting to OSGi bundle events.

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to do a refresh on the hibernate-bundle as it's not aware of a change to your updated bundle, it still holds a reference to the old bundle. Therefore an update always also needs a refresh for the other bundles. 
This is by design as an Update just updates the Bundle itself but doesn't trigger an "update" of the resolving of all other dependencies. Therefore it is mandatory for you to trigger that "update" on the resolving of bundles yourself with the refresh command. This can either be done with the ID of the hibernate-bundle or "refresh" only. The second will update the resolving of all bundles you have installed.